# Facebook SDK: Knowing if sharing took place

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am sharing a link from my app using code from HelloFacebookSample, but I can't figure out how to know if sharing actually took place. I use this for sharing:

```
FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:urlToShare
                                                      name:@"Hello Facebook"
                                                   caption:nil
                                               description:@"The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration."
                                                   picture:nil
                                               clientState:nil
                                                   handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                       if (error) {
                                                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                       } else {
                                                           NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                       }
                                                       NSLog(@"Results: %@",results);
                                                   }];
```

and that works fine. The problem is accessing the results dictionary. I figured out that I need to add this to the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  // attempt to extract a token from the url
  return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                    NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                  }];
}
```

Otherwise the handler isn't run at all. The weird thing now is that in the sample app the results dictionary has two fields,

```
completionGesture = cancel;
didComplete = 1;
```

but when I use the exact same code in my own app, on the same phone, the dictionary only contains

```
didComplete = 1;
```

Why is that, and is there some other way to find out if the user shared or cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this section here on what you can expect in the result dictionary, and why only some values are available:

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/share-dialog/#handling-responses

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand the words but I am not really sure what they mean by "logged in to facebook _in the app_". I mean, while it is true that I never explicitly log in, I am able to post stuff, so I have to be logged in in some sense. And in the example app, even if I remove everything but the share button and that same snippet of code, it still works, it still returns the full dictionary.

Comment: In any case, is there a way to find out if the user cancelled or not, without explicitly logging in?

Comment: There's logging into YOUR app, and logging into the Facebook app. If the user has never logged into YOUR app (using Facebook login), then the only key you'll see is didComplete. If the user has authorized your app, then you'll also see completionGesture. To answer your second question more directly, No, there's no way to find out if the user has cancelled without them explicitly authorizing your app.

Comment: OK, I see. Then it is a bit strange that it still works in the stripped down example, but perhaps it still remembers being authorized from before I removed the LoginView.

Comment: It's if your app has EVER been authorized by the user (including on different devices).